# UI Panel Lerp Update

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, panel

I have a couple of UI Panels that I wish to move into the screen area.
I have made a script to attach to each Panel but it does little when I do my changes in Update which I am now using LateUpdate instead which almost works.
The panel will move into the screen only very slightly as if LateUpdate was called only once.
Oddly, when I do the same with a second Panel, it's 'HidePanel' method then lets the first Panel come fully into view. Then the first Panel's 'HidePanel' method works correctly.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class DisplayPanel : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool isMovingIn    = false;
    private bool isMovingOut = false;
    private Vector2 posOut;             //The panel's position hidden just outside the RH screen edge.
    private Vector2 posIn;              //The panel’s position shown just inside the RH screen edge.
    private Vector2 pos;                //The panel’s current position.


    //Initialization
    void Start () {

        RectTransform rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        posOut = new Vector2 ((Screen.width + rt.rect.width)/2, 0);   //To be hidden just outside the RH screen edge.
        posIn  = new Vector2 (posOut.x - rt.rect.width, 0);           //To be visible just inside the RH screen edge.
        pos = posOut; 
        rt.anchoredPosition = pos;                                    //Move panel to the RH screen edge.       

    }

    public void LateUpdate() {

        RectTransform rt = GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
        rt.anchoredPosition = pos;      //Need this for start..

        if (isMovingIn == true) {

            if ((int)pos.x != (int)posIn.x) {         //Casting floats to ints so we can eventually find equality.

                pos = Vector2.Lerp (pos, posIn, 2*Time.deltaTime);
                rt.anchoredPosition = pos;
            } 
            else {
                isMovingIn = false;                           }
        }
        else
        if (isMovingOut == true) {

            if ( (int)pos.x != (int)posOut.x) {

                pos = Vector2.Lerp (pos, posOut, 2 * Time.deltaTime);
                rt.anchoredPosition = pos;                                                      } 
            else {
                isMovingOut = false;            }
        }

    }

    public void DisplayPanel(){

        isMovingOut = false;            
        isMovingIn = true;

    }

    public void HidePanel(){                        

        isMovingIn = false;
        isMovingOut = true;

    }

}//End class
```

Comment: You should not try to perform those movement by code but more likely think of Animation instead. You can then define the movement visually in space and time.

Comment: What's the full script? Looking at the above info, isMovingOut will never be true. Hard to find where you made the mistake from what you shared.

Comment: I think it is something to do with the canvas which my two panels share and FixedUpdate not being called to complete the Panel move within the screen.

Comment: Everts, I need to set the current screen size in the animator, I was creating a clip in code but had a small issue so tried this instead.

Comment: Mark, I deleted all the guff and renamed things for clarity.

Comment: Mark, HidePanel() sets isMovingOut to true. I have 2 buttons to call HidePanel() and DisplayPanel().

Comment: I have found that 'time.DeltaTime' is zero sometimes in LateUpdate. I'm not sure if it is a bug or not but it is supposed to be the amount of time since the last frame. When zero Lerp fails to make any movement.